# Close button on Jquery Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a custom alert ui setup for jquery-ui, but for some reason my close button doesn't close the window. Below is my code. I am attempting to utilize the override alert() with jQuery UI as mentioned in this link. Any assistance is appreciated.
https://andrewensley.com/2012/07/override-alert-with-jquery-ui-dialog/

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type ="text/javascript">
    window.alert = function (message) {
        $(document.createElement('div'))
            .attr({ title: 'Invoice Information', 'class': 'alert' })
            .html(message)
            .dialog({
                draggable: true,
                modal: true,
                resizable: false,
                width: 'auto',
                buttons: {
                    OK: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                },
                close: function () { $(this).remove();}
            });
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Looks like it works in a newer version of jquery. https://jsbin.com/nasoviqojo/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Why are you loading two versions of jQuery?

Comment: @Barmar twas' an accident.

Comment: It works for me with jquery 1.9.1: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/h6g10z7s/

Comment: Weird. Works for me as well on jsfiddle, but not in VS17. Also when I use IE I get the error JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'dialog'

Comment: `.html(message).dialog(...)` - what if message is `undefined`? `html(undefined)` will return empty string, and type `string` dosen't have method `dialog`.

Comment: It should always be defined based on how I have my controller and view setup. There will always be a dialog for null files, uploaded files, or any error. This error was specific to IE.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by simply moving my renders and script links to my header and moving my JS script to the body.